# Trivializing the vector bundle of $S^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-bundle

It's know that in general we do not have that $TS^n\cong S^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$. But I saw the interesting fact that is that we will have $TS^n \times \mathbb{R}\cong S^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, so we get kinda of a trivialization . Now I have been trying to see why this is true but I got nowhere, does anyone have any suggestions ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the standard embedding $\iota:S^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and in particular the tangent/normal splitting $T\mathbb{R}^{n+1}|_{S^n}\cong TS^n\oplus NS^n$. Can you use this to show your statement is true?

Comment: We know that $T\mathbb{R}^{n+1}|_{S^n}\cong S^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, now I am not sure what to do with the normal bundle,  I think it's actually the first time I am seeing the concept in "action", but maybe $NS^n \cong \mathbb{R}$?Since I think it will have dimension 1 . Maybe I am confusing things up.@Kajelad

Comment: The argument is $TS^n\times\mathbb{R}\cong TS^n\oplus(S^n\times\mathbb{R})$, and that $NS^n$ is trivial, i.e. $NS^n\cong S^n\times\mathbb{R}$ (since $NS^n$ has rank $1$ a nonvanishing section).

Comment: To see the normal bundle is trivial, just see that $(v,t)\in S^n \times \mathbb{R} \mapsto (v,tv ) \in NS$ is a trivialisation